# TypeORM transaction with query builder

Tags: transactions, nestjs, typeorm, query-builder

I have some question with `TypeORM` transaction.
So my code is like below:

```js
  public createOrderTransaction = async (
    data: CreateOrderInputDTO,
  ): Promise<Order> => {
    const queryRunner = this.connection.createQueryRunner();
    await queryRunner.startTransaction();
    try {
      const order = await this.createOrder(data);
      await this.createOrderRecord(order.id, data);
      await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
      return order;
    } catch (error) {
      this.logger.error(
        "Transaction Error: 'createOrderTransaction' is failed: ",
        error,
      );
      if (queryRunner.isTransactionActive) {
        await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();
      }
    }
  };
```

And one function like `createOrder` use query builder:

```js
private createOrder = async (data: CreateOrderInputDTO): Promise<Order> => {
    const { identifiers } = await this.orderRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('order')
      .insert()
      .into(Order)
      .values([data])
      .execute();

    await this.saveOrderDetail(identifiers[0].id, data.orderDetails);

    await this.orderRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('order')
      .relation(Order, 'orderDetails')
      .of(identifiers[0].id)
      .add(data.orderDetails);

    return this.getOrder(identifiers[0].id);
  };
```

But when I try it, and if it fire some error middle of logic, rollback doesn't work.
The way I see it, It seem that `query builder` doesn't support transaction.
So Is there any way to use `quert builder` with `transaction`?

Answer (score 3):

Self Answer...
After I am looking into TypeORM `index.d.ts`, I take it that there are some parameter in `createQueryBuilder` named `queryRunner` so. If you input there your own query runner for transaction you can use `queryBuilder` with `queryRunner`

As like:

```js
  public createOrderTransaction = async (
    data: CreateOrderInputDTO,
  ): Promise<Order> => {
    const queryRunner = this.connection.createQueryRunner();

    await queryRunner.connect();
    await queryRunner.startTransaction();
    try {
      const order = await this.createOrder(data, queryRunner);
      await this.createOrderRecord(order.id, data, queryRunner);
      await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
      return order;
    } catch (error) {
      this.logger.error(
        "Transaction Error: 'createOrderTransaction' is failed: ",
        error,
      );
      if (queryRunner.isTransactionActive) {
        await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();
      }
    }
  };
```

`createOrder` as like:

```js
 private createOrderRecord = async (
    orderId: string,
    data: CreateOrderInputDTO,
    queryRunner?: QueryRunner,
  ): Promise<void> => {
    await this.orderRecordRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('order_record', queryRunner)
      .insert()
      .into(OrderRecord)
      .values([
        {
          ...data,
          orderId,
          createdAt: new Date(),
        },
      ])
      .execute();

    await this.orderRecordRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('order_record', queryRunner)
      .relation(OrderRecord, 'orderDetails')
      .of(orderId)
      .add(data.orderDetails);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps help anyone facing this question, but instead of doing in above answer, we can use dataSource, as suggested in this [official TypeOrm transaction document](https://typeorm.io/transactions#creating-and-using-transactions), and instead of adding Entity in queryBuilder, add it to `.from()`

```
await myDataSource.manager.transaction(async (transactionalEntityManager) => {
// We can use 'transactionalEntityManager' to create queryBuilder here:
await transactionalEntityManager.createQueryBuilder()
  .from(Order, 'order')
  .insert()
  .into(OrderRecord)
  .values([
    {
      ...data,
      orderId,
      createdAt: new Date(),
    },
  ])
  .execute();

// And of course similar with relation table:
await transactionalEntityManager
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .from(Order, 'order')
  .relation(OrderRecord, 'orderDetails')
  .of(orderId)
  .add(data.orderDetails);
})
```