# TypeOrm transaction with method in other service

Tags: transactions, nestjs, typeorm

I used typeorm with nestjs.
but i don't know how to use transaction with method

for example,

```
async createTrack(track) {
try {

  const createdTrack = await this.createTrack(track);

  //this.boardService.createBoard will work by transaction.
  const board = await this.boardService.createBoard({
      ...track.board
  });

  return board;
} catch (e) {
  throw e;
}
```

i wanna use method of boardSerivce with trasaction.

how to do?

---

i solved it.

try it. [TypeORM transaction with query builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68697866/typeorm-transaction-with-query-builder)

or

use https://github.com/odavid/typeorm-transactional-cls-hooked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the docs? https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#transactions

Copy from the docs above

```
const queryRunner = this.connection.createQueryRunner();

  await queryRunner.connect();
  await queryRunner.startTransaction();
  try {
    await queryRunner.manager.save(users[0]);
    await queryRunner.manager.save(users[1]);

    await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
  } catch (err) {
    // since we have errors lets rollback the changes we made
    await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();
  } finally {
    // you need to release a queryRunner which was manually instantiated
    await queryRunner.release();
  }
```

Comment: yes, i checked it. but how to use method with queryRunner? because i wanna recycle my custom method in other service. i don't wanna rewrithe same code that same function

Comment: thanks. l solve it. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68697866/typeorm-transaction-with-query-builder

Comment: that's good, you can update your original question to reflect what you actually want and what you have found so that other people can benefit from it